# DSE 5 docvalues supported?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Does DSE 5 support docvalues and, if so, is it going to be supported in 5.1? As [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/docValues.html?hl=docvalues) piece of documentation has conflicting information, indicating support throughout the article but having this note at the end:

> **Note**: docValues are not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation bug, `docValues` are supported. There may be a specific edge case that the docs meant to convey that somehow got cut off.

I will investigate and update both this answer and the docs.

#### Update

It looks like the current limitation is the combination of boolean fields and docvalues. Docs will be updated.